# Voltages at the terminals of a three-terminal system with one voltage probe

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, voltage, quantum-transport

We have a three terminal system with one voltage probe as shown in the picture bellow. If I want to calculate voltages at each terminal, how should I proceed? Should I solve this system of equations

$$I_1=G_{11}V_1+G_{12}V_2+G_{13}V_3$$
$$0=G_{21}V_1+G_{22}V_2+G_{23}V_3$$
$$I_3=G_{31}V_1+G_{32}V_2+G_{33}V_3$$

where $G_{ij}$ are the conductances between terminals, with the additional condition

$$G_{11}+G_{21}+G_{31}=0$$
$$G_{12}+G_{22}+G_{32}=0$$
$$G_{13}+G_{23}+G_{33}=0$$

?

[image]

EDIT: I have the solution to this problem, the voltages should be

$$V_1=\frac{(G_{31}+G_{32})I_1+G_{13}I_3}{G_{12}G_{31}+G_{12}G_{32}+G_{13}G_{32}}$$
$$V_2=0$$
$$V_3=\frac{(G_{12}+G_{13})I_3+G_{31}I_1}{G_{12}G_{31}+G_{12}G_{32}+G_{13}G_{32}}$$

I just don't know how to arrive at this answer.

Comment: I suppose $I_1=-I_3$ due to the particle conservation. Could you remind me where the last set of relations come from? (It has been some time, since I revised Büttiker.)

Comment: I took that relation from Thomas Ihn book Semiconductor Nanostructures in chapter 13. He says it's a consequence of the conservation of charge.

Comment: This is a trustworthy source. However, in your case the conductances are likely known - you need to solve the first three equations for voltages and current. As I said,  $I_1=-I_3$ (also charge conservation). In addition, one voltage can be taken as the reference, which leaves with with three equations and three unknowns.

Comment: Actually I do have a solution for this problem, that is I know what the voltages should be I just couldn't arrive at the answer. I'll add the solution to the question

Comment: @RogerVadim you do not have to invoke particle or charge conservation to get I1 = -I3. Simply vertically add all 3 equations, and the conditions means that the RHS entirely cancel out to zero. As for solving, I would have chosen to eliminate the diagonal terms of the G matrix by the conditions, and just work with the off-diagonal terms.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent you are using the last three relations, which (as we know) do follow from the charge conservation - you have just provided the proof yourself. Thanks.